# How to fix file system definitely

Tags: 16.04, dual-boot, filesystem, fsck

The file system in which my Ubuntu 16.04 is allocated keeps corrupting and the initramfs shell appears. When this happens, I check the filesystem (sda6) and reboot to use Ubuntu normally, but when I switch on my laptop the problem is back.

Is that a sign that my HDD will break soon? Is it possible to definitively fix this issue?

Thank you.

Comment: You have to fix the underlying problem, usually a bad hard drive, run smartmontools

Comment: Do you dual-boot with Windows? If so, in Windows, have you installed a driver to read/mount ext[2-4] partitions? Different question... have you started the `Disks` app and looked at the SMART data/diags? You may have a failing hard disk.